# Upload file to Rest API in WindowsForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, post

I am able to upload the files to an API, but I need a small help. Right now I just hard-coded it. But actually, I will be having a PDF and XML files in two different local file storage locations, I need to get the files from that location and needs to upload them to API. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

```
private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            UploadFileAsync(@"D:\test\SBP-1102.pdf");                     
    }

    public static async Task UploadFileAsync(string path)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        // we need to send a request with multipart/form-data
        var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();

         // add file and directly upload it
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
        multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "files", Path.GetFileName(path));

        // send request to API
        var url = "https://spaysaas-dev/api/getOCRDocuments";
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, multiForm);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there any exceptions? Can you open the URI in browser? Have you any proxy in your network? There could be many reasons for the problem.

Comment: You could try [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check what's going on.

Comment: I am not sure, whether my code was correct or not. I am not getting any error while running the code

Comment: Try handling [`WebClient.UploadFileCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted?view=netframework-4.8). The `UploadFileCompletedEventArgs` class has an `Error` property that might shed some light on if there is an error occurring?

Comment: Can you provide me where I can use that WebClient.UploadFileCompleted

Comment: @VenkatSunil I posted an answer with how and where you might handle that event.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am able to upload the PDF file to an API using multi-part form data

Answer (score 2):

This answer is incomplete in that it doesn't actually explain why the file isn't being uploaded, but it might help you diagnose the problem.

The documentation on [`WebClient.UploadFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebClient_UploadFileAsync_System_Uri_System_String_) says:

> The file is sent asynchronously using thread resources that are automatically allocated from the thread pool. To receive notification when the file upload completes, add an event handler to the UploadFileCompleted event.

So you could try handling [`WebClient.UploadFileCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted?view=netframework-4.8) and checking the `UploadFileCompletedEventArgs` for errors.

```csharp
private void Upload(string fileName)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadFileCompleted += Client_UploadFileCompleted;
    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://saas-dev/api/getDocs");
        {
           client.Headers.Add("fileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
           client.UploadFileAsync(uri, fileName);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void Client_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   // Check e.Error for errors
}
```

Comment: I have tried with several examples from stack overflow to upload a pdf file to a web api. but nothing helped me.

Can anyone help me with a working sample program to upload a PDF file to a Web API in windows forms C#

Comment: Any sample would probably look like what you already have. Did you try the code above to see if you were getting any errors, and if so what were they? Does the API require authentication, because it doesn't look like you're setting any sort of authentication header? Do you own the Rest API so that you can troubleshoot that end, or is it a third-party API?

Comment: Hi,
I have changed my code and able to upload the files now in multipart form data. But actually I will be having a PDF and XML files in two different file locations and needs to get those files from the filesystems and then I need to upload them to API. Can anyone help me to achieve this?